# How to check that one dictionary can "fit in" another dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

I have a dictionary dict1: `{'id1': 5, 'id2': 1, 'id3': 2}` and dictionary dict2:  `{'id1': 1, 'id2': 4, 'id3': 2, "id4": 9}`.
How can i get a dictionary with keys from dict1 which are in dict2 too and values from dict2 that fit in dict1? imagine that dict1 shows capacities of rooms and dict2 number of people which want to go to certain room. so desired output is: `{'id1': 1, 'id2': 1, 'id3': 2}`. I need to do it with Python

Comment: Are you trying to fit in the smallest values?

Comment: @snakecharmerb imagine that dict1 shows capacities of rooms and dict2 number of people which want to go to certain room.

Comment: Wouldn't your code be better if you used `Counter`s instead of `dict`s? Would make this trivial, too.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using a dict comprehension as per answer by @tzaman , but using a `min` function to choose the smallest value from the two dicts?

```py
dict1 = {'id1': 5, 'id2': 1, 'id3': 2}
dict2 = {'id1': 1, 'id2': 4, 'id3': 2, 'id4': 9}
dict3 = {key: min(dict1[key],dict2[key]) for key in dict1 if key in dict2}
print(dict3)
# {'id1': 1, 'id2': 1, 'id3': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [dict comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/):

```
dict1 = {'id1': 5, 'id2': 1, 'id3': 2}
dict2 = {'id1': 1, 'id2': 4, 'id3': 2, 'id4': 9}
dict3 = {key: min(dict1[key], dict2[key]) for key in dict1 if key in dict2}
# {'id1': 1, 'id2': 1, 'id3': 2}
```

EDIT: Updated to match expected output. You can use the `min` function to get the result you're looking for.

Comment: I noticed that but I'm assuming it's a typo for now given the verbal explanation. Waiting on a response to your comment on the OP.

Comment: That's the same solution the other answer had already...

Comment: @KellyBundy When I posted my original answer OP's intent was unclear and there were no other answers. Are you suggesting I _shouldn't_ correct mine after the clarification? Not to mention, the other answer was explicitly modeled after mine in the first place..

Comment: I might've just deleted it. Then again, if I had "noticed that" difference as you say, I wouldn't have posted in the first place.